# FAKE specify NUnit Namespace/Fixture when running tests

Tags: f#, nunit, f#-fake, f#-fake-4

In my Powershell script (PSAKE), I have the ability to specify the Namespace/Fixture to run when I execute the NUnit test runner.

```
task UnitTest -Depends Compile -Description "Runs only Unit Tests" {
    Invoke-Nunit "$buildOutputDir\$testAssembly.dll" "$testAssembly.Unit" $buildArtifactsDir
}

task IntegrationTest -Depends Compile -Description "Runs only Integration Tests" {
    Invoke-Nunit "$buildOutputDir\$testAssembly.dll" "$testAssembly.Integration" $buildArtifactsDir
}

task FunctionalTest -Depends Compile -Description "Runs only Functional Tests" {
    Invoke-Nunit "$buildOutputDir\$testAssembly.dll" "$testAssembly.Functional" $buildArtifactsDir
}
```

This allows me to have three outputs

```
Unit-TestResults.xml
Integration-TestResults.xml
Functional-TestResults.xml
```

I'm in the process of switching over to FAKE because it's just so much cleaner to maintain, however I can't figure out how to specify the Fixture for my test.

IE: right now I have

```
// Run Tests
Target "Tests" (fun _ ->
    testDlls 
    |> NUnit (fun p -> 
        {p with 
            DisableShadowCopy = true;
            OutputFile = artifactDir + "/TestResults.xml"
    })
)
```

But this runs ALL the tests and drops it into a single output. I'd really like to specify the Fixture, and be able to split it all up. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newest version of FAKE added support for Fixture parameter. You should be able to do:

```
Target "Tests" (fun _ ->
    testDlls 
    |> NUnit (fun p -> 
        {p with 
            Fixture ="Namespace.Unit"
            DisableShadowCopy = true;
            OutputFile = artifactDir + "/Unit-TestResults.xml"
    })
    testDlls 
    |> NUnit (fun p -> 
        {p with 
            Fixture ="Namespace.Integration"
            DisableShadowCopy = true;
            OutputFile = artifactDir + "/Integration-TestResults.xml"
    })
    testDlls 
    |> NUnit (fun p -> 
        {p with 
            Fixture ="Namespace.Functional"
            DisableShadowCopy = true;
            OutputFile = artifactDir + "/Functional-TestResults.xml"
    })
)
```

Comment: sweet! That's really new (I just started using Fake 2 weeks ago). Works like a champ.